# Displayport for DELL T150 server

Tags: graphics-cards, linux, server, pcie

By accident I bought a DELL T150 server, which was shipped with VGA.
I did not expect to receive a VGA port in the year 2022. I tried an active VGA to DP converter, but it does not run stable, when I want to enter the BIOS for example.

I need to upgrade the T150 with a graphic card with display port in order to connect it with all other systems to the KVM switch.

**Requirements**

- just need 2D graphics such as BIOS, or probably X11 and TTY
- 1x display port
- must run out of the box with a current Linux Kernel. Drivers must be part of the open source part of the Kernel. We do not want to struggle with external drivers as often seen with Nvidia or ATI
- the T150 provides a 4th generation PCIe slot
- very low power consumption as the PSU provides just 300 W for the whole system
- **UPDATE:** According to the DELL support the maximum power supply on the motherboard is even limited to **65 W**

Comment: Just curious if you have explored the iDRAC option that the T150 provides? It provides Keyboard+Video+Mouse over ethernet so you can use another PC to remotely manage the server. No need to plug any monitor in to that server itself.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU market is not healthy at the moment, but there are still some GPU's availible that fit your requirements. The  [MSI GeForce GT 1030 Passive LP OC 2GB](https://nl.hardware.info/videokaarten.5/msi-geforce-gt-1030-passive-lp-oc-2gb.398339) can do 2d graphics with BIOS and TTY, although I don't know if it will play well with X11. If you want one that works for sure with all 3, you can use the [MSI Radeon RX 560 Aero ITX OC 4GB](https://nl.hardware.info/videokaarten.5/msi-radeon-rx-560-aero-itx-oc-4gb.398180), although it is almost twice as expensive where I live. (links go to Dutch revieuw site)

Comment: According to the DELL support the maximum power supply on the motherboard is even limited to 65 W. Both graphic cards consume much more in the peak.

Comment: No problem, both of these cards won't use much power when only rendering 2D graphics (my RX 570 uses between 5 and 30W when browsing, those are probably the same terretory)